# How to show alert for duplicated value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I have multiple `input` fields with different values. I can edit them but cannot be empty (if empty show an alert). When I am editing it to new values, if the new value matches with any of the other inputs values, I need an alert *that you cannot use this*.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.selector').change(function () {
    alert();
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/0c0qep6y/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
$('.selector').on('blur',function () {
   if ($('.selector[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').not($(this)).length > 0 || current_value.length == 0 ) {
    alert('duplicate value');
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0c0qep6y/12/

Comment: almost correct,but the cursor is going to the orginal one,i want it to be at the duplicated one

Comment: after i'm pressing ok on alert and click out of that input,it's taking the duplicated value

Comment: change `on` function to `change`.If i use `on` function,on the fly the alerts are coming. When i edit the whole textbox from empty to `newest` i am getting two alerts.I think it's a bad user experience.

Comment: also taking null value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96876/discussion-between-iamraviteja-and-madalin-ivascu).

Comment: one more bug.I am able to add spaces.Not getting alert if i edit any name with blank spaces.

Answer (score 7):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c0qep6y/14/).**

You can refresh the value attribute using `$(this).attr('value', $(this).val());` first, then check if there's any other field with class `selector` has the same value using value selector `$('.selector[value="' + current_value + '"]').length`.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('body').on('blur', '.selector', function () {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());

    if ($('.selector[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length > 1 ) {
        $(this).focus();
        alert('You cannot use this');
    }else if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        alert('Empty value not accepted');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="selector" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" value="older">
```

Comment: `if ($('.selector[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length) { alert('Cannot use'); {`

Comment: Thanks @Tushar for your advice, updating my answer but in think we have to use `length > 1` since we have the current input with this value, please check.

Comment: how to bring back the cursor to duplicated textbox after clicking ok on alert?

Comment: @IamRaviteja `$('.selector[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').not(this).first().focus()` OR to focus current element `$(this).focus()`

Comment: not working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/0c0qep6y/1/),when i change oldest to old

Comment: @IamRaviteja I posted **[Why Jquery selector by 'value' not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063628/why-jquery-selector-by-value-not-work/34063917)** to understand why really selector by 'value' not work in your case here, and based in explanations i have updated my answer, check please.

Comment: cursor is going to original one

Comment: the one we are editing.And i read your question.Can't we do using `text()`

Comment: So you can use just `$(this).focus();` check my update, (`text()` in my question just to show output in page, i can replace alert in your example by showing text in page if you want ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96878/discussion-between-iamraviteja-and-zakaria-acharki).

Comment: one more bug.I am able to add spaces.Not getting alert if i edit any name with blank spaces

Comment: seems to work for me note: if you have different placement of spaces thy are counted as different inputs

Answer (score 0):

Use unique Id's for each input text field and get the values of them in your JavaScript method using `getElementById("[YourDefinedId]")` and compare them with each other and show alter.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="selector" id="first" value="new">
<input type="text" class="selector" id="second" value="old">
<input type="text" class="selector" id="third" value="newest">
<input type="text" class="selector" id="fourth" value="oldest">
<input type="text" class="selector" id="fifth" value="older">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function compareValues(){

var first = getElementById("first").value;
var second = getElementById("second").value;
var third = getElementById("third").value; 
var fourth = getElementById("fourth").value;
var fifth = getElementById("fifth").value;

//Now you can compare them using null check and empty.

}
```

Comment: i cannot use,it is more complex as i need to compare with every `id`

Comment: you can create and assign dynamically `id` to `inputText` which will help you in comparing using loops.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('.selector').change(function () {
  var changedItem = $(this);
  var otherSelectors = $(".selector").not(changedItem);
  var matchingItemPresent = [];
  $.each(otherSelectors, function (count, item) {
    $(item).val().trim()== changedItem.val().trim();
    matchingItemPresent.push($(item));
  });
  
  matchingItemPresent.length > 0 ? alert("Duplicate entry..same value exists in another field") : $.noop();
  
  matchingItemPresent[0].focus();
  console.log(matchingItemPresent[0]);
});
```

updated to focus on the text box [JS Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/0c0qep6y/9/)