# Why Jquery selector by 'value' not work in case of dynamic change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm not sure why jquery selector `value` not work, Trying to change the value of inputs to `"a"` but the `length` not increment, please check the simple example bellow:

```js
$('body').on('input', '.example', function() {
  $('#result').text($('.example[value="a"]').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="example" value="a">
<input type="text" class="example" value="b">
<input type="text" class="example" value="c">

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are changing value dynamically it wouldn't get selected by attribute selector. You can use `filter()` instead.

> Attribute selector will not check the dom node's **value property** it only targets the **element's attribute**

```js
$('body').on('input', '.example', function() {
  $('#result').text($('.example').filter(function() {
    return this.value == 'a'
  }).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="example" value="a">
<input type="text" class="example" value="b">
<input type="text" class="example" value="c">

<div id='result'></div>
```

---

Or you need to manually update the element attribute on input event

```js
$('body').on('input', '.example', function() {
  $(this).attr('value', this.value);
  $('#result').text($('.example[value="a"]').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="example" value="a">
<input type="text" class="example" value="b">
<input type="text" class="example" value="c">

<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is why is not work, not how to get it work.

Comment: Yes i see but that not respond really my answer why changing value dynamically it wouldn't get selected by attribute selector.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: because you are updating the `property` not `attribute`;

Comment: Until set the value attribute, the value set is availale in selector [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofcfeqLr/)

Answer (score 1):

The `value` **attribute** describes the *default* value not the *current* value. You can't use an attribute selector to solve this problem because you want to deal with current values.

Instead you need to get all your inputs and test their *current* values one by one.

You can use [the `filter` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for that.

```js
$('body').on('input', '.example', function() {
  $('#result').text(
      $('.example').filter(function (index, element) {
          return ( element.value === "a" );
      }).length
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="example" value="a">
<input type="text" class="example" value="b">
<input type="text" class="example" value="c">

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```js
$('body').on('input', '.example', function () 
{
   $('#result').text( $('.example[value="a"]').val().length );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="example" value="a">
<input type="text" class="example" value="b">
<input type="text" class="example" value="c">

<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: this wont work as this returns the length of the value, not the number of elements present in the page.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question