# How to properly use jquery val() to match CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with some inputs and a CSS attached to them that uses attribute value selectors to change the background color of the input depending on the value.

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><style>
    input[value="foo"] { background-color: red; }
  </style></head>
  <body>
    <form>
     <input value="foo" />
     <button/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I use `foo` as a value when loading, as in the code, the field will be red on loading, but if I change it, it will stay red. Same thing if I change the value of the input to `foo`, it will not change the background color.

Similarly if I use `.val()` in jQuery. Apparently a "dynamic" value is changed in these cases, while the CSS is referring to a "static" value.

```
$('button').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('input[value="foo"]').val('bar');
  // $('input[value="bar"]').val('baz'); // nothing is found
});
```

I expect this code to change the field from `foo` to `bar`, then `bar` to `baz`, but in the second selector the field is not found.

If I use the `attr` method, things seems to work, but in jQuery documentation (and many answers here on SO), `val` is the way to go.

Why is it so and why shall I use `val()` at all?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063660/965834) should help. Basically, use `.filter` or `.attr` as you already attempted.

Comment: In my answer I'm trying to explain your basic misunderstanding.

Comment: What  are the details of the actual problem? Is the color change based entirely on if the value has been updated from its original attribute?

Comment: @doodlemeister the actual problem is that I wanted to add an :pseudo element near empty input fields, but I had issues with that due to how value selector work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Why is it so..."*

That's an attribute selector, and the attribute doesn't change when you update the `.value` property, so you'd need to explicitly change the attribute.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('input[value="foo"]').val('bar').attr("value", "bar");
  $('input[value="bar"]').val('baz');
});
```

```css
input[value="foo"] {
  background-color: red;
}

input[value="bar"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<form>
  <input value="foo" />
  <button/>
</form>
```

But that's not going to work when the user changes the value unless you wire up an `.on("input"...` handler to keep the attribute in sync with the property.

```js
$("input").on("input", function() {
  this.setAttribute("value", this.value);
});
```

```css
input[value="foo"] {
  background-color: red;
}

input[value="bar"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<form>
  Change the value to "bar"
  <input value="foo" />
</form>
```

> *"...and why shall I use `val()` at all?"*

Simply to get and set the value while retaining the original value via the attribute.

It's not all that common to need them to be sync'd. DOM selection by value is a little bit like DOM selection by text content. It's just not needed all that often, and sometimes there's a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Which is why OP shouldn't even attempt to do so. His problem is understanding the difference between the HTML attribute value, and the DOM API input elements value property. That is what answer elaborates on.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciated your explanation regarding the selectors.

Comment: `<button/>` is not allowed. Elements that may have content cannot be self-closing.

Answer (score 1):

```
input[value="foo"]
```

selects `input` elements which have an explicit **attribute** `value` that equals `foo`.

Typing `foo` into an `input` element **does not create such an attribute**, nor does typing anything else *delete* an attribute on an `input` that has the attribute `value="foo"`.

jQuery's `val()` is the correct approach to read the value, the problem is that your selector `$('input[value="bar"]')` cannot find anything because setting the value **property** of the `input` does not change/add the **attribute**.

Comment: Thanks, I apprecciate your effort to explain the difference. Now I wonder what about the jQuery `prop('value')` in this case? Is that equivalent to `val()`?

Comment: Read https://api.jquery.com/prop/ "Attributes vs Properties" Also note that the HTML attribute `value` has only one purpose - pre-setting the value via HTML.

Comment: I did, but it talks mostly about boolean properties and default attributes and IMO it does not explain the difference well.

Comment: The difference is that `prop` is to be used on *properties* whereas `attr` is to be used on *attributes*. Is the difference still not clear? Because wanting to access the current value of an input is such a common requirement, and mainly because jQuery didn't have a `prop` method before 1.6, jQuery offers the specialized variant of `prop` called `val`. It was never removed because that would break alot of code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet explains well

```js
$input = $('input')

console.log('val:', $input.val())
console.log('attr:', $input.attr('value'))

// attr will get the attribute from html not the *dynamic* value has been set
$input.val('bar')
console.log('val:', $input.val())
console.log('attr:', $input.attr('value'))

// same here when you use val you change the property value of input not the attribute
$input.attr('value', 'bazzz')

console.log('val:', $input.val())
console.log('attr:', $input.attr('value'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am certainly wrong on this for anyone who knows the technicalities of HTML, but for my own intuition, I always thought of anything that goes into the HTML file as an **attribute** and any values after that as **properties** (I guess you can call them runtime values). If you want a deeper understanding, you'll need to google it as I just do not have such knowledge :) Just keep in my mind, my summary here is terribly oversimplified.

You can do the following experiment. On Chrome, if you hit Ctrl+J (sorry, I don't know what the combo is for other browsers), you can pop open the javascript console. In there, enter

```
$("input[value=foo]").val("bar");
```

Then go to the DOM explorer and notice that the value **attribute** has not changed. In order to change it, you need to use the function

```
$("input[value=foo]").attr("value","bar");
```

Then you will be able to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: While your intuition is understandable, it's unfortunately not that simple. Some attributes are actually mapped to their corresponding property, so when the property changes, so does the attribute. Just so happens that this is not the case for `value`.