# Return value of document.querySelectorAll("[value='a']") would not change after element value being modified

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selectors-api

Return value of `document.querySelectorAll("[value='a']")` would not change after element value being modified, neither browser modified nor javascript modified.

I run windows 10 and chrome 73 on the client. below is the demo:

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var modify = document.getElementById("modify");

select.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("text1.value: " + text1.value);
    console.log("text2.value: " + text2.value);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[value='a']"));
});

modify.addEventListener("click", function () {
    text1.value = "a";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2" value="a">
<input type="button" id="select" value="select">
<input type="button" id="modify" value="modify">
```

1. Click `select` button I get `NodeList [input#text2]` logged in the browser console.
2. Click `modify` button or directly modify the `text1` value.
3. Click `select` button I get `NodeList [input#text2]`, but I expect the output to be `NodeList(2) [input#text1, input#text2]`.

Looks like selector only apply to initial html value. I tried google the problem, but there is no any clue out there.

1. If this behavior is the standard behavior, what is the purpose?
2. Is there a workaround if I want the expected return value `NodeList(2) [input#text1, input#text2]`?

Comment: Attribute selectors will not detect dom node's value attribute. use a class for all your text fields. get elements by class and filter out based on their value. see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063628/why-jquery-selector-by-value-not-work-in-case-of-dynamic-change

Comment: You need to use `text1.setAttribute("value", "a");` to change what the selector looks for.

Comment: Thanks  for your responding. I tried setAttribute and getAttribue, and the result is opposite: "Attribute selectors will 'only' detect dom node's value attribute". I will post my demo as reference later.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z6uv852/) To clarify the result: **1.** Input field value in the browser **IS** the value property`element.value`. **2.** Setting value property will **NOT** update the value attribute. **3.** Setting value attribute in the html tag or using `setAttribute()` before setting value property will update the value property only one time, subsequent setting will not. **4.** Attribute selectors will **ONLY** detect dom node's value attribute.

Comment: As a result, I have to use `document.querySelectorAll("*")` and filter them as you said to catch the value property changes. If there is something wrong above, please feel free to correct me, thanks.